# force ignore line larastan-phpstan

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

i´m getting this error when i´m doing scann in my proyect:

```
Class App\Jobs\ProcessCalculoGrupo uses unknown trait App\Fabricas\SidraExtraccionTrait.  
          Learn more at https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols                       
  32     No error to ignore is reported on line 32.
```

My code it´s:

```
class ProcessCalculoGrupo implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    use \App\Fabricas\SidraExtraccionTrait; // this it´s my line 32
```

this file: `\App\Fabricas\SidraExtraccionTrait;` in this moment, not exists, because i´m modifying one proyect with several years of life. Now it´s possible that this code be used again, but now i need ignore this error.

I try ignore this line with:

```
/** @phpstan-ignore-next-line */
/* @phpstan-ignore-next-line */
// @phpstan-ignore-next-line
```

Also i tray set php-doc in line with previous notation. But i return same problem.

In documentation i can show:

```
Please note that some selected serious errors (like autoloading issues, parent class not found, parse errors, etc.) cannot be ignored and must be solved to get to zero errors when running PHPStan.
```

but, how i can solve this problem?

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment the invalid trait use for now.